# Can only update a mounted or mounting component. findless error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Note: Find this issue is harder than others**. I know this question has been asked before me, but I need help!

I've been getting this error for the 3 days, but I don't know about this error. even I search a lot, check the original code, but nothing happened!

```
`proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting 
 component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or 
 forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the _class2 component.`
```

***ContactData.js***, I believe the error is happing here, because when I trigger the button, so I get that.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Button from '../../../components/UI/Button/Button';
import axios from '../../../axios-orders';
import classes from './ContactData.css';
import Spinner from '../../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner';


class ContactData extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: false
    }

    orderHandler = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState( { loading: true } );

        const order = {
            // ingredients: this.props.ingredients,
            // price: this.props.price,
            // // customer: {
            // //     name: 'Max Schwarzmüller',
            // //     address: {
            // //         street: 'Teststreet 1',
            // //         zipCode: '41351',
            // //         country: 'Germany'
            // //     },
            // //     email: 'test@test.com'
            // // },
            // deliveryMethod: 'fastest'
        }
        axios.post( '/orders.json', order )
            .then( response => {
                this.setState( { loading: false } );
                this.props.history.push('/');

            } )
            .catch( error => {
                this.setState( { loading: false } );
                this.props.history.push('/');

            } );
            console.log('9')

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);

        let form = <Spinner />

        if( !this.state.loading )
        {
            form = (
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
                    <Button btnType="Success" clicked={this.orderHandler}>Order</Button>
                </form>
            );
        }
        console.log('10')


        return (
            <div className={classes.Contact_data}>
                <h1> Your Contact Data !</h1>
                {form}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactData;
```

The Whole Repo is uploaded here[enter link description here](https://github.com/ShinyBoy0/React-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `setState()` is called in a component even though the component got already unmounted because of navigating away from a component, `history.push('/')` in this case.

You can add a `isMounted` check before calling `setState()`, like so:

```
class ContactData extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  orderHandler = (event) => {
    .then( response => {
      // add check here
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState( { loading: false } );
      }
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }

  componentDidmount() {
    this._isMounted = true
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not helping this method, It's looks like a challenge!

Comment: Hi, I just edited the code snippet. Just try with the updated snippet once. isMounted will set to true in componentDidMount

Comment: The same behavior. can you play with code here is repo https://github.com/ShinyBoy0/React-error